# Transform matrices with Matrix.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter in XNA: vanishing point to center

Tags: matrix, 3d, xna, translation, transform

I'm trying to get the following perspective of view: [image]

In essence I'm doing a 2D game with some 3D graphics so I switched from `Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter` to `Matrix.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter`

I have drawn a primitive and by decreasing it's z-index it goes further away, but it always vanishes in direction of the (0, 0) (top-left), while the vanishing point should be the center.

My transform settings now look like this ((640, 360) is the center of the screen):

```
basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveOffCenter(0, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 1, 10);
basicEffect.View = Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(640, 360, 1), new Vector3(640, 360, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
basicEffect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);
```

I can't get the vanishing point to the center of the screen. I managed to (sort of) do it with CreatePerspective view but I want to keep using CreatePerspectiveOffCenter because I can translate normal pixel positions easily to the 3D space. What am I missing?

Comment: Would you elaborate on why you want to use `CreatePerspectiveOffCenter`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understanding is this: CreatePerspectiveOffCenter is a function that converts pixel coordinates (top-left 0,0 and bottom-right viewport.width, viewport, height) to space world points (0, 0 center, x -1 to 1, y -1 to 1), which is handy for me because I'm essentially doing a 2D game. Am I correct and is there a reason why I should or shouldn't use CreatePerspectiveOffCenter for this goal?

Comment: Moreover, I think I almost got it to work but I'm doing something wrong. Right now I have a perfect translation when z-Index = 0 of my primitives, they have perfect positions and I can draw them using normal pixel coordinates. But when I decrease the x-Index, the primitives move to the top-left corner of the screen, rather than the center. (I changed back to Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0)); )

Comment: What I meant to ask was, why aren't you using the simple method `CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView` isntead of trying to create some off-center thing?  It sure looks like you want a simple perspective.  

Also, the way you describe these methods is backwards.  They convert 3d coordinates into screenspace; not the other way.  If that is the reason you are using these methods, you are approaching the problem the wrong way.  http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Comment: Yes `CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView` was indeed the way to go, achieved it by using that method. I thought the OffCenter method was useful for my goal, but now I abandoned that idea I'm still not sure what that method is for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the following. If you're looking for a solution to create a 3d view with a '2D feel' this might come in handy. With these translations a z-index of 0 exactly matches the screen's width and height and the vanishing point is in the center of the screen.

```
basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)Math.PI / 2f, 1, 1f / 1000, 1000f);
basicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 1f), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
basicEffect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);
```